# convert eclipse plugin project into maven project programatically

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins

I have a requirement like, I have to create a eclipse plugin project with custom folder structure which I am able to do successfully.

Next step is that I want to make the projet which is created during runtime using my plugin to have maven dependency management, i.e. every project I create with my wizard should be having maven dependency management.

Has anybody got some idea how I can achive this other than Tycho.

NOTE:While searching for the solution I came across tycho maven plugin but it only builds the eclipse plugin project,does not make it a maven project (As per my understanding)

Answer (score 1):

There is no straightforward way to making a project both a Maven project *and* an Eclipse plug-in project. There are different rules for the Maven and Eclipse build system, different ideas to tackle differences.

As you said, Tycho does not make an Eclipse project a Maven project in the traditional sense (e.g. Maven-style dependency management), only makes Maven aware of the Eclipse rules. Luckily, it allows you to compile your plug-ins using Maven (at least with mvn3) really simple.

If you don't need your project to compile in Eclipse, you could use other tools like [Maven Pax](http://www.ops4j.org/projects/pax/construct/maven-pax-plugin/), but I do not know the capabilities and limitations of them.

So generally, if Pax works out working, it might help, otherwise I don't think there is a tool already created because of the main logical differences between the Maven and OSGi/Eclipse plug-in world.